# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map') al intentar mostrar datos en pantalla

Tags: reactjs, firestore

Estoy haciendo un programa con React y Firebase, pero al momento de mostrar los datos en pantalla este me tira este error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')

el cual solo ocurre al agregar estas líneas de código:

```
const { links, setLinks } = useState([]);

  const addOrEditLink = async (linkObjet) => {
    await addDoc(collection(db, "tareas"), linkObjet);
  };

  const getLinks = async () => {
    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "tareas"));
    const docs = [];
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      docs.push({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id });
    });
    console.log(docs);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getLinks();
  }, []);

return (
<div>
  <Home addOrEditLink={addOrEditLink} />
  <div>
    {links.map((tareas) => (
      <div>
        <h2> {tareas.titulo} </h2>
        <h2> {tareas.descripcion} </h2>
      </div>
    ))}
  </div>
</div>
```

);

Esto solo ocurre cuando agrego esto, ya que si lo miro en consola sí me da los datos que tengo en Firestore. ¿Hay una forma en que pueda mostrar mi contenido en pantalla que no sea así?

Comment: en la inicializacion de links va entre corchetes, no entre paréntesis. const [variable, setVariable] = useState([]);

Comment: Otra cosa, en la función getLinks, al terminar tendrías que hacer un `setLinks(docs)` para que luego react te repintara los datos

Comment: Gracias hermano, no me di cuenta de los [ ] te agradezco demasiado